# Thread safety of iterator.next()

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, thread-safety

If I have an `Iterator` shared among multiple threads, with each thread calling:

```
// Inside a thread
int myValue = iterator.next();
```

what is a possible outcome?

**(Ignoring the fact that next() may throw a NoSuchElementException) If the iterator is an iterator over an ArrayList, is it possible that multiple threads may end up with the same value inside the `myValue` variable?**

Is the code below one way to resolve this? (apart from using Java 8 streams as described here [Passing a List Iterator to multiple Threads in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222548/passing-a-list-iterator-to-multiple-threads-in-java)).

```
// Inside a thread
int myValue;
synchronized(iterator)
{
    myValue = iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: Iterators should  not be shared between threads. And it is generally not thread-safe to use an iterator on a collection that another thread could be modifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR; Never share Iterators between Threads!**

Considering the most common use of an iterator for looping over content, you will likely encounter the following snippet:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object nextItem = iterator.next();
}
```

Now consider the possibility that another Thread performs the exact same operations. Since you cannot control Thread scheduling, the following may happen on an Iterator with a single element:

```
Thread 1: hasNext? true
Thread 2: hasNext? true
Thread 1: next() //but if this was the last element...
Thread 2: next() //...this will throw NoSuchElementException
```

Iterators may also support `Iterator.remove()`, which can lead to `ConcurrentModificationException` when you operate on shared Collections.

**Can we end up with the same value in different Threads?**

In a similar fashion to the above, consider this very simple Iterator implementation (simplified code):

```
class SimpleIterator implements Iterator {
    ArrayList source;
    int currentIndex;
    hasNext() {
        return currentIndex<source.size();
    }
    next() {
         Object o = source.get(currentIndex);
         currentIndex++;
         return o;
    }
}
```

here we may end up with:

```
Thread 1: get(currentIndex) //Object A
Thread 2: get(currentIndex) //also Object A
Thread 1: currentIndex++
Thread 2: currentIndex++  //you have skipped an element
```

The answer here is **yes**, but it's important to note that it very much depends on the implementation. It's much safer not to go there at all.

**Repeat: In general you should never share Iterators between Threads.**

Comment: (Ignoring the fact that next() may throw a NoSuchElementException) If the iterator is an iterator over an ArrayList, is it possible that multiple threads may end up with the same value inside the myValue variable?

Comment: Yes, I would consider it possible, depending on the Iterator implementation. Consider similar interleaving as per my example, then consider what happens if the Iterator internally simply points at its current index in an ArrayList. You could end up with a repeat and the next item skipped due to double retrieve then double increment of the index.

Comment: IMO, You could repeat that last sentence, "...never share Iterators...," Once up front, and once at the end.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it that multiple threads may end up with the same value inside the
> myValue variable?

It's not guaranteed.

Since `iterator` is not thread-safe, you should synchronize on the collection's object e.g.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = obj.iterator();

synchronized (obj) {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int myValue = iterator.next();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is synchronizing on the iterator (rather than the collection) as I have done in my post incorrect? Assuming the collection is an `ArrayList`?

Comment: > Is synchronizing on the iterator (rather than the collection) as I have done in my post incorrect? Yes, if the collection is shared

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `List#iterator()` is **inconsistent** across `List` implementations.

`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, will throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if modified during iteration. To avoid this use a synchronizedList() and lock the `List` during iteration.

`Vector`is synchronized by deafult but the `Iterator` is not thread safe.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList`, [we can iterate the `List` safely, even if concurrent modification is happening while iteration](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-on-write-arraylist).

Comment: (Ignoring the fact that next() may throw a NoSuchElementException) If the iterator is an iterator over an ArrayList, is it possible that multiple threads may end up with the same value inside the myValue variable?